# How to make customised siema.js slider navigation update on auto paging?

Tags: javascript, html, slider, carousel

I want to make a carousel with siema.js on my sample webshop page. Siema is lightweight - but doesn't come with too many features. I had to create my own navigation for it and also hat to make it switch to the next page after a few seconds. It has an easy-to-use API.

However, I couldn't make it change the state of my navigation buttons (which are radio inputs basically). In the constructor, it has a onInit and onChange function, but I didn't manage to get the result I wanted, not even with the callbacks example provided (https://codepen.io/pawelgrzybek/pen/MpvYNr).

I tried to add

```
    document.querySelector(`.slider-nav:nth-child(${this.currentSlide.toString()})`)
            .setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
```

but it did not work. Most of the times, when I tried to access the currentSlide either with this.currentSlide or carousel.currentSlide, I got undefined as a result.

I also tried making a custom event, dispatching it from inside the onChange function in the constructor, but when I added an event listener, I got the error: `TypeError: carousel.addEventListener is not a function`.

Also tried to add it inside the onInit function:
        onInit: () => { 
            setInterval(() => {

```
            carousel.next();
                        document.querySelector(`.slider-nav:nth-child(${this.currentSlide.toString()})`).setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
        }, 5000);
    },
```

and there I got the error that `document.querySelector(...) is null`.

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/S7R1DR/94ejpm1o/13/)

**JavaScript**

```
const carousel = new Siema({
    selector: '#carousel',
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'ease-out',
    perPage: 1,
    startIndex: 0,
    draggable: true,
    multipleDrag: false,
    threshold: 20,
    loop: true,
    rtl: false,
    onInit: () => { 
        setInterval(() => {
            carousel.next();
        }, 5000);
    },
    onChange: () => {},
      });

Siema.prototype.addPagination = function() {
const type = 'radio',
    name = 'slider',
    title = 'slide',
    cls = 'slider-nav';

for (let i = 0; i < carousel.innerElements.length; i++) {
    title.value = 'slide'+ (i).toString();
    const btn = document.createElement('input');
    btn.setAttribute('type', type);
    btn.setAttribute('name', name);
    btn.setAttribute('title', title + (i+1).toString());
    btn.setAttribute('class', cls);

    btn.addEventListener('click', () => this.goTo(i));

    document.getElementById('carousel-nav').appendChild(btn);
    }
}

carousel.addPagination();
```

Right now, it generates as many buttons as needed, the paging with the buttons is working with the goTo function, but I want the slider to check the first radio input when it loads in, and on every auto sliding to check the current slide's radio button.

I am no expert in JS and would appreciate any help :)